# What is the meaning of polyfills in Angular4?

Tags: angular

I actually don't understood what is the meaning of polyfills.

Is it a new HTML5 technique or a JavaScript library? I never heard this word before HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont know asbout AngularJS...
but i ll give one example..
A polyfill is a browser fallback, made in JavaScript, that allows functionality you expect to work in modern browsers to work in older browsers

It's sort of an HTML5 technique, since it is used in conjunction with HTML5, but it's not part of HTML5, and you can have polyfills without having HTML5 (for example, to support CSS3 techniques you want).

Follow this-
 http://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill/

Answer (score 4):

According to official angular docs

> Angular is built on the latest standards of the web platform. Targeting such a wide range of browsers is challenging because they do not support all features of modern browsers.
>
> You compensate by loading polyfill scripts ("polyfills") for the browsers that you must support.

In other words, polyfills have some js libraries which are used for **BROWSER COMPATIBILITY**. To support modern browsers features in older browsers.